# When i store a comment, ERROR: Too few arguments to function | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I am building a comment function in Laravel.

When I store a comment in my website, it has a problem that appear a error message.
[enter image description here][1]

How can I fix it please?

I post code now

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController;
use App\Models\Article;

Route::resource('articles', ArticlesController::class);

Route::get('/', [ArticlesController::class, 'index'])->name('root');

Route::resource('articles.comments', CommentsController::class);

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/userhome', function () {
    return view('userhome');
})->name('userhome');

Route::get('/userhome', function() {
    // 利用SQL WHERE印出用戶發表過的所有資料到HOME
    $articles = Article::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(5);
    return view('userhome', ['articles' => $articles]);
})->name('userhome');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

CommentsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, $id) {
        $request->validate([
            'content' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data = new Comment;
        $data->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $data->article_id = $id;
        $data->content = $request->content;
        $data->save();
        return redirect()->route('root')->with('notice', '文章發表成功！');
        // return redirect('articles/'. $id)->with('notice', '回覆發表成功！');
    }
}
```

show.blade.php

```
<form class="container-fluid" action="{{ route('articles.comments.store')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <p>{{ Auth::user()->name }}：</p>
    <div class="flex field my-2">
        <textarea name="content" id="" cols="50" rows="1" class="container border border-gray-300 p-2" placeholder="請輸入回覆內容">{{ old('content')}}</textarea>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" class="px-3 py-3 ml-2 rounded bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 text-nowrap">回覆</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Instead of posting links to screenshots it would be better to post the code directly in here (only the relevant code of course!). On a first glance it looks like your comments expect the article ID as parameter in the controller. However, you defined the comment routes via `resource` without any relation to articles. So your routing does't know anything about the `$id` parameter. this link perfectly desribes this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: @Frnak thank you very much, so should I change that Route::resource('articles.comments', PhotoCommentController::class);

Comment: obviously not `PhotoCommentController` as you don't have that controller :). `Route::resource('articles.comments', CommentsController::class);` should do the trick

Comment: Excuse me, when I use your method, and the action of form change to action="{{ route('articles.comments.store')}}". It has a new problem now. "Missing required parameter for [Route: articles.comments.store] [URI: articles/{article}/comments] [Missing parameter: article]." Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

you are using **resource routes** for `CommentsController` as defined in your `web.php`

`Route::resource('comments', CommentsController::class);`

if you look at your routes schema using `php artisan route:list` command, you'll see `/comments` route with POST method points to your **store()** method at **CommentsController** which is defined for your application alongisde 6 other resource routes because you defined **resource routes** in your web.php

as you can see `/comments` does not have any parameter, (like `/comments/{id}`) so your store() method can't have two parameters like you wrote

❌ `public function store(Request $request, $id)`

✅ instead, embed the article's id as a hidden form input, then get it in store() method like

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $data->article_id = $request->input('article_id');
```

best regards ;)

Comment: while the explanation of the error is correct - I dislike the solution. A more RESTful (and therefore typical) solution would be what is suggested in the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: thanks your reply abed, but I don't want input the article_id with users in website, I prefer use that original $id with ArticlesController

Comment: perfect & clean solution, you are right thanks  @frnak

Comment: this is a hidden input & showing article id to users is not an issue. having `$id` as a `store()` method parameter means you have to pass it to the method like `/comments/3` in the form's action attribute, which makes no different @jey-feng

Comment: "Missing required parameter for [Route: articles.comments.store] [URI: articles/{article}/comments] [Missing parameter: article]."  Do you know what happen in my show.blade.php? Help me check it please

Comment: you need to pass the article id as second parameter of `route()` helper. so write it like `route('articles.comments.store', $article_id)` in the form's action attribute, @jay-feng

Comment: I recently solved it by myself, my solution is route('articles.comments.store', $article->id). I tried your solution "$article_id", it would be error "Undefined variable $article_id". However, I appreciate all you help, thank you dude@MuhammadAliAbed